# Understanding generics and comparable in Java

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I am struggling with creating generic data types that require that its element to be comparable.

I have attempted to construct what I think is the most basic implementation of this, and it still is not working.

```
public class GenericPair<T> {
    T thing1;
    T thing2;

    public GenericPair(T thing1, T thing2){
        this.thing1 = thing1;
        this.thing2 = thing2;
    }   


    public <T extends Comparable<T>> int isSorted(){ 
        return thing1.compareTo(thing2);
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args){
        GenericPair<Integer> onetwo = new GenericPair<Integer>(1, 2); 
        System.out.println(onetwo.isSorted());
    }   
}
```

My understanding is that > requires that whatever type T ends up, it must implement comparable and therefore must have a compareTo() function. In this case Integers should have this functionality right?

I am getting the error:

```
GenericPair.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
    return thing1.compareTo(thing2);
                 ^
    symbol:   method compareTo(T)
    location: variable thing1 of type T
    where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class GenericPair
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> int isSorted(){ 
    return thing1.compareTo(thing2);
}
```

This new `T` is hiding the type parameter of your class (also called `T`). They are two different types! And `thing1` and `thing2` are instances of your *class's* generic type, which aren't necessarily comparable.

So, you should declare your class's type parameter to be comparable instead:

```
class GenericPair<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

And now:

```
public int isSorted(){ 
    return thing1.compareTo(thing2);  // thing1 and thing2 are comparable now
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that generic `T` for the whole class doesn't know a `compareTo` method. Even if you declare `<T extends Comparable<T>>` for this single method, you're just creating a new `T` that hides the definition of the generic `T` from the class.

A solution may be declaring `T extends Comparable<T>` in the class itself:

```
class GenericPair<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    public int isSorted() {
        return thing1.compareTo(thing2);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the most correct, it's in the class declaration

Answer (score 0):

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> int isSorted(){ 
    return thing1.compareTo(thing2);
}
```

You can't have a method that imposes new constraints on the generic type parameter defined by the class.  You would have to declare

```
public class GenericPair<T extends Comparable<T>> {
   public int isSorted() {
     return thing1.compareTo(thing2);
   }
}
```

Comment: Although you can have a method that hides the generic type parameter defined by the class.

Comment: Yes indeed, I was just pointing out that's what's happening here.